# How do I model group memberships in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

What would be an optimal way to implement group memberships in Cassandra? I need the following operations:

1. Create a new group with an optional list of initial members.
2. Delete a group.
3. Add a user to a group.
4. Delete a user from a group.
5. List all members of a group.
6. List all group memberships.

90%+ (maybe even 99%) of all operations on the DB would be listing all members of a group. There's the choice between using sets for maintaining the memberships of a group vs. making each member of a group a row on its own. The load is fairly significant requiring a large cluster.

Users would be just identified by their ID, which is a short string. Groups would only need to be identified by a string like a UUID. No names or other metadata needed.

The biggest challenge is how to support listing all group memberships efficiently. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The first principle of data modelling in Cassandra is **design a table for each application query**. You need to list the application queries first THEN design a table for each of those app queries.

DBAs from a relational background typically do the reverse -- they tend to focus on worrying about how the data is structured on the table then later try to design queries for the app. This however does not work when it comes to Cassandra because the tables end up not being optimised for the app queries.

In your case, the application query looks something like:

> Retrieve the list of user IDs for group ID X.

Rewriting this in something more SQL-like:

```
SELECT userid FROM table WHERE groupid = X
```

This app query indicates that the table needs to be partitioned by the group ID (`groupid`) which contains one or more rows of user IDs (`userid`). The design (schema) for this table looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    groupid uuid,
    userid text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (groupid, userid)
)
```

When you query this table with:

```
SELECT userid FROM groups WHERE groupid = ?
```

it will return one or more rows of `userid`. Cheers!